# Transferring a file from Windows client to Android server

Tags: c#, android, tcp, file-transfer, networkstream

I need to transfer a file from a certain computer with windows to an android device on another network; how can I recognize the android's server's IP?

Hello.

So I have this application in windows that takes any file from a path, converts it in byte[], connects to a certain IP and sends it with NetworkStream;

on the other end I have a Xamarin Android application that listens for incoming connections from any IP, and then saves the incoming bytes to a folder.

It works on a local network, but now I want it to work remotely in 2 separate networks (say, the PC connected via ethernet and the Android phone connected via 4G). I work on the assumption that I already have the IPv4 address of the Android machine.

I tried to look around for it and I think I need to do a DNS lookup to understand where to send my bytes, but I really can't figure out how.

I think I'm missing some crucial step on how to translate the IP of the phone so that the Windows app can connect to it. What am I missing?

//Windows Client Code
//Sends a file when a button is clicked

```
        string ipaddress = IPText.Text; //takes the written IP address
        string filepath = ApkPathText.Text; //takes the written path to the file
        Stream filestream;
        byte[] bytestream;

        try {
            filestream = File.OpenRead(filepath);
            bytestream = new byte[filestream.Length];
            filestream.Read(bytestream, 0, (int)filestream.Length);
        } catch (UnauthorizedAccessException err) {
            return;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException err) {
            return;
        } catch (IOException err) {
            return;
        }

        NetworkStream networkStream;
        TcpClient clientSocket;

        try {
            clientSocket = new TcpClient(ipaddress, 8080); //Maybe it needs a different ip??
            networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            networkStream.Write(bytestream, 0, bytestream.GetLength(0));
            networkStream.Close();
        } catch (SocketException se) {
            DebugLog("Impossibile aprire socket! ["+se+"]");
            return;
        }

    }
```

//Android Server code

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{

    private Socket client;

    private void Listener() {
        TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8080);
        tcpListener.Start();
        bool can_Exit = false;
        do {
            Socket socket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
            if (socket.Connected) {

                ThreadStart tStarter = new ThreadStart(Acceptor);
                Thread tAcceptor = new Thread(tStarter);
                tAcceptor.Start();
            }
        } while (!can_Exit);
    }

    private void Acceptor() {
        Socket socket = (Socket)client;
        NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(socket);
        int thisRead = 0;
        int blockSize = 1024;
        Byte[] dataStream = new Byte[blockSize];
        Stream fileStream = null;
        lock (this) {
            String dirPath = @"sdcard/";
            String filePath = @"file.file";
            String totalPath = dirPath + filePath;
            if (!Directory.Exists(dirPath)) {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);
            }
            try {
                fileStream = File.OpenWrite(totalPath);
            } catch (IOException err) {
                return;
            }
            bool can_Exit = false;
            try {
                do {
                    thisRead = networkStream.Read(dataStream, 0, blockSize);
                    fileStream.Write(dataStream, 0, thisRead);
                    if (thisRead == 0) {

                        can_Exit = true;
                    }
                } while (!can_Exit);
                fileStream.Close();
            } catch (UnauthorizedAccessException err) {
                return;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException err) {
                return;
            } catch (IOException err) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        ThreadStart tStarter = new ThreadStart(Listener);
        Thread tListener = new Thread(tStarter);
        tListener.Start();
    }
}
```

}

It should connect successfully, but instead the Windows client returns an "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"

Comment: Ok, I'm fairly certain that I should make for the listener an IPEndPoint with IPAddress 0.0.0.0 on the port 8080, so that it can listen on all the interfaces the device has; 

however, it still doesn't connect with my TcpClient.

I've also changed the Server code from the generic "Socket" to accept a "TcpClient". But still nothing.

I think that I'm either missing a section where I determine WHERE the the server is from the Client, or that I need to open some kind of firewall from the android device.

Will report if I have futher insight.

Comment: Tried port forwarding to no avail.

Comment: I'm using FWD on my device to forward the port, and it shows that the IP of the machine is private. I think I might need a public IP - or a way to connect through the public IP I get through icanhazip and then through the private IP of the machine.

Comment: Trying to use OpenNAT to determine the address of the server.

Comment: Minor breakthrough. By using OpenNAT and a Socket to listen with the command "Socket.SetIPProtectionLevel(IPProtectionLevel.Unrestricted);" I am able to see my service from https://canyouseeme.org/ .......for a little while. At least it looks like a promising road?

Answer (score 0):

So, direct connection is still an *incognita* for me. So I opted for a different kind of structure.

I've put an FTP server as a middle man, where both the Android device and the PC can connect and make operations.

It's not optimal, and certainly not the solution I was looking for...but it works, for now.

If you, reader from the future, are looking for a solution with direct connection in .NET, I can only point you to OpenNAT and/or Windows Communication Foundation. In both cases I was able to make a service that was available online, but it fluctuated a lot and wasn't ideal for transferring big files. Maybe it's just because I'm not skilled enough - yet. You might have more luck in the futuristic year you find yourself in.

Good luck, programmer!